# I keep on getting the following error when I try to send email using laravel

Tags: laravel

I keep on getting the following error when I try to send email on live server.

Does anybody have any idea how to solve this?

Error

Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.mailtrap.io:2525 (Connection refused)

https://flareapp.io/share/x5MqzN5k

Comment: post how you set your email env's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have already created an account with mailtrap.io and that you have access.
Second configure your .env file and enter the following parameters as below.

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io

MAIL_PORT=2525

MAIL_USERNAME=81UserIDd47b***

MAIL_PASSWORD=36ba146c85*****

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Remplacer le MAIL_USERNAME et le
MAIL_PASSWORD par les accès que vous avez obtenus chez mailtrap.io